# Simple Modal not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is URL of the page which works fine in Firefox, chrome, Safari but for some reason it is not working in IE 9.

Modal shows a banner when page loads.

http://tinyurl.com/b52drmt

link for modal i am using http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Script looks fine to me, unfortunately i am not able to fix it so far.

Comment: IE9 throws `SCRIPT438: Object doesnt's support the use of an attribute or method removeExpression. 
jquery.simplemodal.js, line 15 char 440`

Comment: I downloaded the latest js files for same & it works fine now in IE 9, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved issue by downloading latest js files for the same .... now works fine in IE 9